How to fix chaining loader issue
This is the error I am facing -
common_app.chunk.js:158268 ./node_modules/@netless/synced-store/node_modules/value-enhancer/dist/index.js 27:29
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (27:29)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| };
| var INIT_VALUE = {};

var isVal = (val2) => !!val2?.$valCompute;
| var markVal = identity;

Tried updating node module but nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
